# logstash splits event field values and assign to @metadata field

Tags: filter, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I have a `logstash` `event`, which has the following field

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2016.08.09",
  "_type": "log",
  "_id": "AVZvz2ix",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "function_name~execute||line_no~128||debug_message~id was not found",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2016-08-09T14:57:00.147Z",
    "beat": {
      "hostname": "coredev",
      "name": "coredev"
    },
    "count": 1,
    "fields": null,
    "input_type": "log",
    "offset": 22299196,
    "source": "/project_root/project_1/log/core.log",
    "type": "log",
    "host": "coredev",
    "tags": [
      "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
    ]
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1470754620147
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1470754620147
  ]
}
```

I am wondering how to use `filter` (`kv` maybe?) to extract `core.log` from `"source": "/project_root/project_1/log/core.log"`, and put it in e.g. `[@metadata][log_type]`, and so later on, I can use `log_type` in `output` to create an unique `index`, composing of hostname + logtype + timestamp, e.g.

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][_source][host]}-%{[@metadata][log_type]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage the [`mutate/gsub` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub) in order to achieve this:

```
filter {
  # add the log_type metadata field
  mutate {
    add_field => {"[@metadata][log_type]" => "%{source}"}
  }
  # remove everything up to the last slash
  mutate {
    gsub => [ "[@metadata][log_type]", "^.*\/", "" ]
  }
}
```

Then you can modify your `elasticsearch` output like this:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{host}-%{[@metadata][log_type]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```