# logstash RegexpError: invalid char in group name

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have been trying the following regex in `logstash.config` to extract a partial string from a field,

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2016.08.09",
  "_type": "log",
  "_id": "AVZvz2ix",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "function_name~execute||line_no~128||debug_message~id was not found",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2016-08-09T14:57:00.147Z",
    "beat": {
      "hostname": "coredev",
      "name": "coredev"
    },
    "count": 1,
    "fields": null,
    "input_type": "log",
    "offset": 22299196,
    "source": "/project_root/project_1/log/core.log",
    "type": "log",
    "host": "coredev",
    "tags": [
      "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
    ]
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1470754620147
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1470754620147
  ]
}
```

For example, extracting `core.log` from `"source": "/project_root/project_1/log/core.log"`.

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => ["source", "/(?<[@metadata][log_type]>[^/]+)$"]
  }
}
```

but got an error,

```
{:timestamp=>"2016-08-16T10:09:41.352000+0000", :message=>"Pipeline aborted due to error", :exception=>#<RegexpError: invalid char in group name <[@metadata][log_type]>: /\/(?<[@metadata][log_type]>[^\/]+)$/m>, :backtrace=>["org/jruby/RubyRegexp.java:1434:in `initialize'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/jls-grok-0.11.2/lib/grok-pure.rb:127:in `compile'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-grok-2.0.5/lib/logstash/filters/grok.rb:264:in `register'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-grok-2.0.5/lib/logstash/filters/grok.rb:259:in `register'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-grok-2.0.5/lib/logstash/filters/grok.rb:255:in `register'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:182:in `start_workers'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:182:in `start_workers'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:136:in `run'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/agent.rb:473:in `start_pipeline'"], :level=>:error}
```

What's wrong with the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you didn't like the [solution using split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38900150/logstash-splits-event-field-values-and-assign-to-metadata-field) ;-)

Anyway, you need to specify your custom pattern like this:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => ["source", ".*\/(?<log_type>.*)"]
  }
}
```

Note, however, that due to [this issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-grok/issues/66) it is not possible to specify a nested field in the named capture of the grok regular expression.

This will capture `core.log` and store it in the `log_type` field of your event. You can then move `log_type` to the `@metadata` field if you wish.